# Nancy httpfile issue

Tags: c#, linux, mono, filestream, nancy

i have problems during parsing request files.
my file size is 1338521 bytes, but Nancy says, that file size is some times 1751049 or 3200349.
on my windows pc it works fine, on linux server this problem appears, so i can't save file.

```
string result = Convert.ToBase64String(Core.ReadBytesFromStream(file.Value));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(result)))
{
    using (Bitmap bm2 = new Bitmap(ms))
    {
        bm2.Save(path);
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert the file like that.

```
var filename = Path.Combine(storagePath, Request.Files[0].Name);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
     Request.Files[0].Value.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Validate the file when it comes in to ensure the extension is accepted, create a save path, and copy the stream to a new file on the filesystem.

That's it.

Comment: i also tryied this. on windows it works fine, on linux, images more than 500kb are damaging, i don't know how to explain this, but here is saved image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ORKn1.jpg and here is original one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mTsE2.jpg file size: 718kb. do you know how to fix it?